# Selenium how to close notfication alert with @FindBy?

Tags: java, selenium

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YoV0.png)
I need help by making a annotation to cancel that notfication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot , you have to disable notification using browser setting.

```
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
```

or

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// 1 to allow and 2 to block
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```